# Where are the Javascript password validations files in SugarCRM?

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords, sugarcrm

I want to add some extra password validations in SugarCRM. I want to add that using javascript. But I don't know, where SugarCRM stores javascript files related to password validation. So, please guide me on this. Thank you.

Comment: config_override.php available in root folder?

Comment: yeah, its available, but I want to add some extra password validation, when user tries to changes his password. Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's too late, but still no one has answered this question, so I am posting here.

In following path, you'll see the `PasswordRequirementBox.js` file, which Sugar uses for Password validation purpose. You can extend these functions also.

```
<root_of_crm>/jssource/src_files/modules/Users/
```

Let me know, if you need any more help.

Comment: Hey @Tony, thanks. I have already solved this. Somehow, I managed to find this file, that you mentioned in your post. But what I didn't understatnd that, in this file already password validation code is already available, but still it is not working in SugarCRM CE edition. Let me know, if you know anything. I am closing this question by accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please goto ***modules/Users*** there you will find **login.php** file. This file is performing the validation functionality. In this file you will see it is also requiring **login.js** Which is also at same path.

I hope this will help you.